# Are there any common themes in the dreams so many Muslims have that prompt them to come to Jesus?

Tags: soteriology, islam, theophany

I understand that a good number of believers, who were once Muslim, became Christians after having a dream where Jesus appears to them and tells them to follow Him.

Examples are recorded in books like [*I Dared to Call Him Father*](http://www.newtestamentpattern.net/bookreviews/biography-modern/idaredtocallhimfather.htm) and others.

Are there any common themes in these dreams?  Does Jesus Himself always appear?

Also, is this common for people in any other religion like Hinduism, Taoism, or anything like that?

Comment: Can I tag this [tag:private-revelation]? I don't know if it's a term you'd normally use.

Comment: [tag:theophany] would be better, I think.

Comment: @PeterTurner both I think work.  Thanks... didn't see that tag.

Comment: This is an awesome question. When I was in Kazakhstan, the missionaries there were telling me this is happening a lot.  There was even a movie about it.

Comment: Why and how to you infer that dreams are reliable?

Comment: If there were only a few isolated instances of this, credibility would certainly be lacking.  However, it is so widespread that it becomes quite credible.  Additionally, these dreams result in devout members of another religion, at great peril to themselves, embracing Christianity, which they formerly completely despised.  So, the evidence is quite compelling.

Answer (score 2):

I have only heard of this happening en masse in the Muslim world.  The testimonies I have heard from missionaries to Turkey and Iran are these people are seeing Jesus appear to them.

One other notable example I've heard of this happening recently (1996) to a non-Muslim is Joshua Blahyi, formerly known as General Butt Naked in Liberia.  He tells of a man and a woman appearing to him, and the man spoke in his old dialect.  He says the man was Jesus.  I don't know who the woman was.

You can see his story in [a piece by the Vice Guide to Travel](http://www.vice.com/the-vice-guide-to-travel/the-vice-guide-to-liberia-6)[possibly NSFW].

Comment: I actually saw a movie about that, and I remember something about a supernatural occurance, now that you mention it.

Comment: Could you label this link NSFW?  My browser was blocked (thankfully) for nudity.

Comment: Sorry friend.  I did a quick google search for the video, but didn't pay attention to the page to see if there was anything bad there.  I watched the video on Netflix, it's available there in its entirety.